# highchart maps: mapbubble set custom x,y coordinates for the series for bubbles on same country

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am working ona highchart mapbubble project, where i am plotting 2 different series with data for same countries as in the image below.
The problem is the bubbles for both are overlapping on eachother as in the marked section.
I tried changing the x,y position values for one series but its not working.
Is there any particular property of mapbubble will be helpful in achieving this.
Please help!!
I am using angular 6 and highcharts 6.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set reposition bubbles by using `attr` method, for example:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var point = this.series[2].points[0];

    point.graphic.attr({
      translateX: 20
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fobekgrx/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: it gives error as ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined
    at a.Chart.load

Comment: Hi @Thilak raj, That is only an example, you need to adapt it to your case.